# Create a custom attribute that would hint to Resharper that property is used implicitly

Tags: c#, resharper, custom-attributes, rider

If I define a class with a public property that is not used explicitly, but annotate it with either `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty` or `JetBrains.Annotations.UsedImplicitly`, then I won't get any usage warnings.

Can I define such custom attribute? My motivation is that I already have some custom attributes to mark such properties and adding this feature on top of them would save some redundant annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Resharper Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#MeansImplicitUseAttribute) you should be able to apply a `MeansImplicitUseAttribute`  to your own attribute's definition.

> **MeansImplicitUseAttribute**
>
> Should be used on attributes so that symbols marked with such attributes are not reported as unused. The marked attribute behaves the same as UsedImplicitlyAttribute.